# When installing SharePoint Server 2019 I get the message: "this tool does not support the current operating system

Tags: sharepoint

When installing SharePoint Server 2019, I get the message:
`this tool does not support the current operating system`;

What should I do?
How to install `SharePoint Server 2019` or `SharePoint Server` of another version on `Windows-10`?

I downloaded `SharePoint Server 2019`.
Link - https://www.microsoft.com/ru-RU/download/details.aspx?id=57462

I'm running `splash.hta`.
I run `Install required Software`.

I use `Windows-10x64`.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint 2019 can be installed on:

- Windows Server 2016 Standard or Datacenter
- Windows Server 2019 Standard or Datacenter
- Windows Server 2022 Standard or Datacenter

For more details check [Hardware and software requirements for SharePoint Server 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/hardware-and-software-requirements-2019)

Comment: **1.** Is there any online test version of MS Project Server where you can practice development?
In particular:
- raise the SOAP service;
 - working with the bus;
 - copying tasks, assignments, connections from one project to another;
**2.** Can I create a project in Visual Studio that will contain SharePoint and use MS Project Server?
As a result, develop on this project and test this project in Windows-10.
Or do you still need:
- Windows Server 2016 Standard; 
 - Windows Server 2019 Standard.